# Created a simple jquery div fadeIn, but also need a skip button to skip the animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a simple div fade in with jquery using .fadeIn, but I also need a bit of code that skips the animation and goes straight to the end, I've tried a .click function but to no effect!

Here's my code and a jsfiddle...

```
<div class="logo-masthead">
</div>
<div class="video">
</div>
<div class="skip" id="skip-intro">
skip
</div>

$('.logo-masthead').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');

$("#skip-intro").click(function() {
$('.logo-masthead').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/37t6vvc7/

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: replace with this $("#skip-intro").click(function() { _ because you are calling ID

Comment: thanks @stanze, that was actually just a typo, it still doesn't work

Comment: So you want to stop fadeIn effect on click of skip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `.stop().fadeOut()` to stop FadeIn effect.

```
$("#skip-intro").click(function() {
$('.logo-masthead').stop().fadeOut();
});
```